# Pause animation on mouseover

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I am using a jQuery script to fade in and out a bunch of `<p>....</p>` tags which works fine but I need the animation to pause on mouseover and resume on mouse out! Is there any method I can add to the script to handle this?

```js
$(function() {
  function InOut(elem) {
    elem.delay()
      .fadeIn(600)
      .delay(5000)
      .fadeOut(600,
        function() {
          if (elem.next().length > 0) {
            InOut(elem.next());
          } else {
            InOut(elem.siblings(':first'));
          }

        }
      );
  }

  $('#anidiv p').hide();
  InOut($('#anidiv p:first'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="anidiv">
  <p>Pause jquery animation on mouseover...1</p>
  <p>Pause jquery animation on mouseover...2</p>
  <p>Pause jquery animation on mouseover...3</p>
  <p>Pause jquery animation on mouseover...4</p>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EDbjw/)

Comment: I'd use this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Pause-Resume-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking the visibility to continue you can put some 
class or anything that suit you to distinguish the current show element from the others.

```
   $('#anidiv p').hide();
InOut($('#anidiv p:first'));

function InOut(elem) {
    elem.delay().fadeIn(600).delay(5000).fadeOut(600, function() {
        if (elem.next().length > 0) {
            InOut($(this).next());
        }
        else {
            InOut($(this).siblings(':first'));
        }

    });
}

$('#anidiv p').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true);
});
$('#anidiv p').mouseout(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":visible") == true) {
        InOut($(this));
    }
});
```

[stop animation on mouseover](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVZVQ/3/)

Comment: This cancels, but does not pause and resume, the animation

Comment: yes it does, it restarts the time. did you wait for it to continue?

Comment: I didn't think that is what the asker wanted.  Instead of pausing a series of animations, I imagine pausing one animation in the middle. The opacity should freeze in it's current state on mouseover.

Comment: Actually, looking at the asker's jfiddle you may be right.  Or maybe a combination of both ideas is the correct one.

Comment: @Muhd this is actually what I was after but your idea also does have some interesting concerpt which I wouldnt mind trying out.

Answer (score 1):

[This plugin](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_pause) will give jQuery the functionality to pause and resume individual animations.  For pausing the series of animations, zdrsh's answer should do fine.

Comment: i get this error when trying to view your link @Muhd Sorry, 196.201.51.19 has been greylisted by http:BL.
You may try whitelisting on http://drupal.org/httpbl/whitelist.